# Implement a search filter in <mat-menu> angular

Tags: angular, menu

I have mat-menu like this in my angular application:

```
      <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <div *ngFor="let id of services">
          <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="id !== service_id" (click)="doSomething(id)">
            {{ id }}
          </button>
        </div>
      </mat-menu>
```

I want to add search in mat menu, such that when mat-menu opens there will be search column. Is this possible? If yes, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

you mean something like this?

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <input
    matInput
    placeholder="Search"
    value="Search"
    (click)="$event.stopPropagation();"
  />
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: This is giving search field, but when i am clicking on search and Insert any character. After one character focus on search is gone, and then i have to click search again to get focus

Comment: It is happening only with mat-menu, i tried separately in that case it is working fine

Comment: @404NotFound:
>>"This is giving search field, but when i am clicking on search and Insert any character. After one character focus on search is gone, and then i have to click search again to get focus"<<

i can't reproduce this. do you use my approach? i can write as long as i would and never lose focus